# How do I get the name of div a user must click to appear in a text div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

Currently I am developing a game and right now the user see's and hears a flash on the buttons they have to click

Background on the game there are 4 colors(They never change
) each level the user is given a random sequence it increases each level and the timer counts down and increments.

**Working example of the game with the sound disabled since it doesn't work in jsfiddle.**

http://jsfiddle.net/uusL7hch/6/

Now My question

I want to add the function to allow the user to see the name of the color they must click along with the  other functions I mentioned above.

For example if the user has to click blue, green and purple

I want them to see the name blue,green and purple each will stay for about 2 seconds then disappear and then the user must enter the right sequence

I have already made the text area where i want the name to appear. But have ran into problems trying to get the text to appear

Here is My JS and HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Elemonator Website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/bootstrap.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/bootstrap-custom.css" media="screen" />
    <link href="http://css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Mechanics/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="Mechanics/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Enable responsive features in IE8 with Respond.js (https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) -->
    <script src="Mechanics/respond.js"></script>      
</head>
<body>

         <div class="wrapper2">
            <div class="pad shape1" data-pad="1">
                <audio preload="auto" class="sound1">
                    <source src="Media/mp3/sounds_01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
                    <source src="Media/ogg/sounds_01.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
                </audio>
            </div>
            <div class="pad shape2" data-pad="2">
                <audio preload="auto" class="sound2">
                    <source src="Media/mp3/sounds_02.mp3"  type="audio/mpeg"/>
                    <source src="Media/ogg/sounds_02.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
                </audio>
            </div>
            <div class="Timer">
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <p><b>Get Ready your time starts when you click start</b></P>
            </div>          
            <div class="TextBox">
            <p><b>Get Ready and click the buttons who's name appear here</b></P>
            </div>
            <div class="pad shape3" data-pad="3">
                <audio preload="auto" class="sound3">
                    <source src="Media/mp3/sounds_03.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
                    <source src="Media/ogg/sounds_03.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
                </audio>
            </div>
            <div class="pad shape4" data-pad="4">
                <audio preload="auto" class="sound4">
                    <source src="Media/mp3/sounds_04.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
                    <source src="Media/ogg/sounds_04.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
                </audio>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="wrapper3">
        <div class="level">
            <h3>Level: 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="score">
            <h3>Score: 0</h3>
        </div>

        <ul class="difficulty">

            <li>
                <input type="radio" class="difOpt" name="difficulty" value="2">Easy
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" class="difOpt" name="difficulty" value="1" checked>Normal
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" class="difOpt" name="difficulty" value="0.5">Hard
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" class="difOpt" name="difficulty" value="0.25">Insane
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="sButton">
            <button class="start">START</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

The JS

```
var game = { //game object
    level: 1, //current level
    turn: 0, //current turn
    difficulty: 1, // user difficulty
    score: 0, //current score
    active: false, //whether a turn is active or not
    handler: false, // whether the click and sound handlers are active
    shape: '.shape', // cached string for the pad class
    genSequence: [], //array containing the generated/randomized pads
    plaSequence: [], //array containing the users pad selections

    init: function () { //initialises the game
        if (this.handler === false) { //checks to see if handlers are already active
            this.initPadHandler(); //if not activate them
        }
        this.newGame(); //reset the game defaults

    },

    initPadHandler: function () {

        that = this;

        $('.pad').on('mouseup', function () {

            if (that.active === true) {

                var pad = parseInt($(this).data('pad'), 10);

                that.flash($(this), 1, 300, pad);

                that.logPlayerSequence(pad);

            }
        });

        this.handler = true;

    },

    newGame: function () { //resets the game and generates a starts a new level

        this.level = 1;
        this.score = 0;
        this.newLevel();
        this.displayLevel();
        this.displayScore();

        //initialize timer to 10 seconds (10.0)
        this.timer = 10;

    },

    newLevel: function () {

        this.genSequence.length = 0;
        this.plaSequence.length = 0;
        this.pos = 0;
        this.turn = 0;
        this.active = true;

        this.randomizePad(this.level); //randomize pad with the correct amount of numbers for this level
        this.displaySequence(); //show the user the sequence
    },

    flash: function (element, times, speed, pad) { //function to make the pads appear to flash

        var that = this; //cache this

        if (times > 0) { //make sure we are supposed to flash
            that.playSound(pad); //play the corresponding pad sound
            element.stop().animate({
                opacity: '1'
            }, { //animate the element to appear to flash
                duration: 50,
                complete: function () {
                    element.stop().animate({
                        opacity: '0.6'
                    }, 200);
                }
            }); //end animation

        }

        if (times > 0) { //call the flash function again until done the correct amount of times 
            setTimeout(function () {
                that.flash(element, times, speed, pad);
            }, speed);
            times -= 1; //times - 1 for each time it's called
        }
    },

    playSound: function (clip) { //plays the sound that corresponds to the pad chosen


        var sound = $('.sound' + clip)[0];
        console.log(sound);
        console.log($('.sound' + clip));
        sound.currentTime = 0; //resets audio position to the start of the clip
        sound.play(); //play the sound


    },

    randomizePad: function (passes) { //generate random numbers and push them to the generated number array iterations determined by current level

        for (i = 0; i < passes; i++) {

            this.genSequence.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        }
    },

    logPlayerSequence: function (pad) { //log the player selected pad to user array and call the checker function

        this.plaSequence.push(pad);
        this.checkSequence(pad);


    },

    checkSequence: function (pad) { //checker function to test if the pad the user pressed was next in the sequence

        that = this;

        if (pad !== this.genSequence[this.turn]) { //if not correct 

            this.incorrectSequence();

        } else { //if correct
            this.keepScore(); //update the score
            this.turn++; //incrememnt the turn

        }

        if (this.turn === this.genSequence.length) { //if completed the whole sequence

            this.level++; //increment level, display it, disable the pads wait 1 second and then reset the game
            this.displayLevel();
            this.active = false;

            // Stop counting when sequence is correct to avoid time running out before starting next level
            clearInterval(this.timerInterval);

            //Add 5.0 seconds each 5th level
            this.timer = 10 + 5 * Math.floor(this.level / 5);

            //Update timerdisplay to show fulltime while displaying next level sequence
            $(".Timer p").html(this.timer);

            setTimeout(function () {
                that.newLevel();
            }, 1000);
        }
    },

    // Countdown and update timer, call incorrectsequence when time's up
    countDown: function () {
        this.timer -= 0.1;
        $(".Timer p").html(this.timer.toFixed(1)); // Display 9.0 instad of 9
        if (this.timer < 0.1) {
            this.incorrectSequence();
        }
    },

    displaySequence: function () { //display the generated sequence to the user

        var that = this;

        var timerCount = 0;

        $.each(this.genSequence, function (index, val) { //iterate over each value in the generated array
            timerCount = index;
            setTimeout(function () {

                that.flash($(that.shape + val), 1, 300, val);

            }, 500 * index * that.difficulty); // multiply timeout by how many items in the array so that they play sequentially and multiply by the difficulty modifier
        });

        // Wait to start timer until full sequence is displayed
        setTimeout(function () {
            that.timerInterval = setInterval(function () {
                that.countDown()
            }, 100)
        }, 500 * timerCount * that.difficulty);
    },

    displayLevel: function () { //just display the current level on screen

        $('.level h2').text('Level: ' + this.level);

    },

    displayScore: function () { //display current score on screen
        $('.score h2').text('Score: ' + this.score);
    },

    keepScore: function () { //keep the score

        var multiplier = 0;

        switch (this.difficulty) //choose points modifier based on difficulty
        {
            case '2':
                multiplier = 1;
                break;

            case '1':
                multiplier = 2;
                break;

            case '0.5':
                multiplier = 3;
                break;

            case '0.25':
                multiplier = 4;
                break;
        }

        this.score += (1 * multiplier); //work out the score

        this.displayScore(); //display score on screen
    },

    incorrectSequence: function () { //if user makes a mistake

        //Stop counting down timer and display start message
        clearInterval(this.timerInterval);
        $(".Timer p").html("Get Ready your time starts when you click start");

        var corPad = this.genSequence[this.turn], //cache the pad number that should have been pressed

            that = this;
        this.active = false;
        this.displayLevel();
        this.displayScore();

        setTimeout(function () { //flash the pad 4 times that should have been pressed
            that.flash($(that.shape + corPad), 4, 300, corPad);
        }, 500);

        $('.start').show(); //enable the start button again and allow difficulty selection again
        $('.difficulty').show();

    }

};
$(document).ready(function () { //document ready

    $('.start').on('mouseup', function () { //initialise a game when the start button is clicked
        $(this).hide();
        game.difficulty = $('input[name=difficulty]:checked').val();
        $('.difficulty').hide();
        game.init();


    });


});
```

Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: There's too much to digest here, try to summarise your question with a simpler fiddle.

Comment: @artm i am not sure what you mean i have linked the fiddle above and the reason there is so much is because I wanted to show the full functionality of the game so it is easier to understand what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to store the different colors in an `array`, in your game object:

```
colors: ["green", "red", "purple", "blue"],
```

Then in your `displaySequence`function, display it with

```
$(".TextBox").children(":first").html("<b>"+that.colors[val-1]+"</b>");
```

`.children(":first")` will get the first element of your `.TextBox` div.
`colors[val-1]` minus 1 because arrays start at 0.

Also you may want to show the answer when user failed  :

```
$(".TextBox").children(":first").html("<b>the good answer was "+that.colors[corPad-1]+"</b>");
```

Set it in your `ìncorrectSequence` function.

```js
var game = { //game object
    level: 1, //current level
    turn: 0, //current turn
    difficulty: 1, // user difficulty
    score: 0, //current score
    active: false, //whether a turn is active or not
    handler: false, // whether the click and sound handlers are active
    shape: '.shape', // cached string for the pad class
    genSequence: [], //array containing the generated/randomized pads
    plaSequence: [], //array containing the users pad selections
    colors: ['green', 'red', 'purple', 'blue'],
    init: function () { //initialises the game
        if (this.handler === false) { //checks to see if handlers are already active
            this.initPadHandler(); //if not activate them
        }
        this.newGame(); //reset the game defaults

    },

    initPadHandler: function () {

        that = this;

        $('.pad').on('mouseup', function () {

            if (that.active === true) {

                var pad = parseInt($(this).data('pad'), 10);

                that.flash($(this), 1, 300, pad);

                that.logPlayerSequence(pad);

            }
        });

        this.handler = true;

    },

    newGame: function () { //resets the game and generates a starts a new level

        this.level = 1;
        this.score = 0;
        this.newLevel();
        this.displayLevel();
        this.displayScore();

        //initialize timer to 10 seconds (10.0)
        this.timer = 10;

    },

    newLevel: function () {

        this.genSequence.length = 0;
        this.plaSequence.length = 0;
        this.pos = 0;
        this.turn = 0;
        this.active = true;

        this.randomizePad(this.level); //randomize pad with the correct amount of numbers for this level
        this.displaySequence(); //show the user the sequence
    },

    flash: function (element, times, speed, pad) { //function to make the pads appear to flash

        var that = this; //cache this

        if (times > 0) { //make sure we are supposed to flash
            that.playSound(pad); //play the corresponding pad sound
            element.stop().animate({
                opacity: '1'
            }, { //animate the element to appear to flash
                duration: 50,
                complete: function () {
                    element.stop().animate({
                        opacity: '0.6'
                    }, 200);
                }
            }); //end animation

        }

        if (times > 0) { //call the flash function again until done the correct amount of times 
            setTimeout(function () {
                that.flash(element, times, speed, pad);
            }, speed);
            times -= 1; //times - 1 for each time it's called
        }
    },

    playSound: function (clip) { //plays the sound that corresponds to the pad chosen
        return; //not supported in jsfiddle

        var sound = $('.sound' + clip)[0];
        console.log(sound);
        console.log($('.sound' + clip));
        sound.currentTime = 0; //resets audio position to the start of the clip
        sound.play(); //play the sound


    },

    randomizePad: function (passes) { //generate random numbers and push them to the generated number array iterations determined by current level

        for (i = 0; i < passes; i++) {

            this.genSequence.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1);
            
        }
    },

    logPlayerSequence: function (pad) { //log the player selected pad to user array and call the checker function

        this.plaSequence.push(pad);
        this.checkSequence(pad);


    },

    checkSequence: function (pad) { //checker function to test if the pad the user pressed was next in the sequence

        that = this;

        if (pad !== this.genSequence[this.turn]) { //if not correct 

            this.incorrectSequence();

        } else { //if correct
            this.keepScore(); //update the score
            this.turn++; //incrememnt the turn

        }

        if (this.turn === this.genSequence.length) { //if completed the whole sequence

            this.level++; //increment level, display it, disable the pads wait 1 second and then reset the game
            this.displayLevel();
            this.active = false;

            // Stop counting when sequence is correct to avoid time running out before starting next level
            clearInterval(this.timerInterval);

            //Add 5.0 seconds each 5th level
            this.timer = 10 + 5 * Math.floor(this.level / 5);

            //Update timerdisplay to show fulltime while displaying next level sequence
            $(".Timer p").html(this.timer);

            setTimeout(function () {
                that.newLevel();
            }, 1000);
        }
    },

    // Countdown and update timer, call incorrectsequence when time's up
    countDown: function () {
        this.timer -= 0.1;
        $(".Timer p").html(this.timer.toFixed(1)); // Display 9.0 instad of 9
        if (this.timer < 0.1) {
            this.incorrectSequence();
        }
    },

    displaySequence: function () { //display the generated sequence to the user

        var that = this;

        var timerCount = 0;

        $.each(this.genSequence, function (index, val) { //iterate over each value in the generated array
            timerCount = index;
            setTimeout(function () {

                that.flash($(that.shape + val), 1, 300, val);
                $(".TextBox").children(":first").html('<b>'+that.colors[val-1]+'</b>');
            }, 500 * index * that.difficulty); // multiply timeout by how many items in the array so that they play sequentially and multiply by the difficulty modifier
        });

        // Wait to start timer until full sequence is displayed
        setTimeout(function () {
            that.timerInterval = setInterval(function () {
                that.countDown()
            }, 100)
        
        setTimeout(function(){$(".TextBox").children(":first").html('');}, 500);
        }, 500 * timerCount * that.difficulty);
    },

    displayLevel: function () { //just display the current level on screen

        $('.level h2').text('Level: ' + this.level);

    },

    displayScore: function () { //display current score on screen
        $('.score h2').text('Score: ' + this.score);
    },

    keepScore: function () { //keep the score

        var multiplier = 0;

        switch (this.difficulty) //choose points modifier based on difficulty
        {
            case '2':
                multiplier = 1;
                break;

            case '1':
                multiplier = 2;
                break;

            case '0.5':
                multiplier = 3;
                break;

            case '0.25':
                multiplier = 4;
                break;
        }

        this.score += (1 * multiplier); //work out the score

        this.displayScore(); //display score on screen
    },

    incorrectSequence: function () { //if user makes a mistake

        //Stop counting down timer and display start message
        clearInterval(this.timerInterval);
        $(".Timer p").html("Get Ready your time starts when you click start");

        var corPad = this.genSequence[this.turn], //cache the pad number that should have been pressed

            that = this;
        this.active = false;
        this.displayLevel();
        this.displayScore();

        setTimeout(function () { //flash the pad 4 times that should have been pressed
            that.flash($(that.shape + corPad), 4, 300, corPad);
        }, 500);
        
        $(".TextBox").children(":first").html("<b>the good answer was "+that.colors[corPad-1]+"</b>");
        
        $('.start').show(); //enable the start button again and allow difficulty selection again
        $('.difficulty').show();

    }

};
$(document).ready(function () { //document ready

    $('.start').on('mouseup', function () { //initialise a game when the start button is clicked
        $(this).hide();
        game.difficulty = $('input[name=difficulty]:checked').val();
        $('.difficulty').hide();
        game.init();


    });


});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.wrapper2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 650px;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}

.wrapper3{
  position: relative;
  margin-top:20px;
  width: 650px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}

.Timer{
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  margin-top:235px;
  margin-left:177px;
  border:5px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color:black;
  text-align:center;
}

.TextBox{
  width:300px;
  height:50px;
  margin-top:30px;
  margin-left:177px;
  border:5px solid white;
  background-color:black;
  text-align:center;
}

.pad {
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.shape1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.shape2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 2.5px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.shape3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 78%;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  margin-right: -50px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: purple;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.shape4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.level, .score {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.sButton {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: black;
  border: 3pt ridge Black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.start {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

   <div class="wrapper2">
   <div class="pad shape1" data-pad="1">
    <audio preload="auto" class="sound1">
     <source src="Media/mp3/sounds_01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
     <source src="Media/ogg/sounds_01.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    </audio>
   </div>
   <div class="pad shape2" data-pad="2">
    <audio preload="auto" class="sound2">
     <source src="Media/mp3/sounds_02.mp3"  type="audio/mpeg"/>
     <source src="Media/ogg/sounds_02.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    </audio>
   </div>
   <div class="Timer">
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
   <p><b>Get Ready your time starts when you click start</b></P>
   </div>   
   <div class="TextBox">
   <p><b>Get Ready and click the buttons who's name appear here</b></P>
   </div>
   <div class="pad shape3" data-pad="3">
    <audio preload="auto" class="sound3">
     <source src="Media/mp3/sounds_03.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
     <source src="Media/ogg/sounds_03.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    </audio>
   </div>
   <div class="pad shape4" data-pad="4">
    <audio preload="auto" class="sound4">
     <source src="Media/mp3/sounds_04.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
     <source src="Media/ogg/sounds_04.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    </audio>
   </div>
  </div>
    <div class="wrapper3">
  <div class="level">
   <h3>Level: 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="score">
   <h3>Score: 0</h3>
  </div>
  
  <ul class="difficulty">

   <li>
    <input type="radio" class="difOpt" name="difficulty" value="2">Easy
   </li>
   <li>
    <input type="radio" class="difOpt" name="difficulty" value="1" checked>Normal
   </li>
   <li>
    <input type="radio" class="difOpt" name="difficulty" value="0.5">Hard
   </li>
   <li>
    <input type="radio" class="difOpt" name="difficulty" value="0.25">Insane
   </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sButton">
   <button class="start">START</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>   
</body>
```

Comment: This is great just one problem with the current code, the last color name in the sequence does not disappear like the rest do any idea how to make the last color name disappear so the user cant see ? Any help would be great on that issue

Comment: Do u have any idea how to hide the last part of the sequence so the user cant see what the last color was thanks , it any idea ?????????????????????

Comment: Sure, just add `setTimeout(function(){$(".TextBox").children(":first").html('');}, 500);` in the Timeout waiting for complete sequence (in `displaySequence`l185-6) or check updated answer